# My Theme's Images are not Responsive on WordPress version 4.4.2

Tags: php, wordpress, image, responsive

I really appreciate the help I get from this community.

Here is my question: I am developing a theme for my self and running WordPress version 4.4.2 on my computer using MAMP. The images I upload to my posts and pages are not coming out responsive. I read that WordPress version 4.4 supports responsive images out of the box.

NOTE: I have not set images sizes or added any code or function that is realted to images on my functions.php file besides:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
```

see screen shot.

[image]

Comment: img {
 max-width:100%;
}

Answer (score 0):

Modify functions.php to generate more image sizes

Every time you upload an image WordPress saves it at its native size. It also automatically generates 3 resized copies in these standard sizes (either height or width may change based on image ratio):

- Thumbnail (150×150)
- Medium (300×300)
- Large (1024×1024)

This is done by modifying the functions.php file. To add new image sizes, you need to add calls to the add_image_size function. Here’s an example that adds four new image sizes:

```
add_image_size( 'sml_size', 300 ); 
add_image_size( 'mid_size', 600 ); 
add_image_size( 'lrg_size', 1200 ); 
add_image_size( 'sup_size', 2400 );
```

And I got some reference in this URL. If you want try this too

[Link for reference](https://www.developersq.com/add-custom-srcset-values-for-responsive-images-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks for the details.

Answer (score 0):

`img{max-width: 100%;height: auto;}` - and combine it with add_image_size. You should not post full size image it thubnails

Comment: Thanks, that sounds just right. Ill test it out in a few hours